# how to calculate percentile in SAS

Tags: sas, dataset, percentile

I want to calculate the 95th percentile of a distribution. I think I cannot use `proc means` because I need the value, while the output of `proc means` is a table. I have to use the percentile to filter the dataset and create another dataset with only the observations greater than the percentile.
Clearly I don't want to use the numeric value..because I want to use it in a `macro`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put summary statistics into macro variables.  You risk loss of precision.
This is based on your cryptic description of the problem.

```
proc means...
   output out=pct95 pct95=
   run;
data subset;
   if _n_ eq 1 then set pct95;
   set data;
   if value < pct95;
   run;
```

Comment: How would precision be lost taking a number from a dataset and putting it into a macro variable?

Comment: A decimal number for example 1/3

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused.  Won't saving 1/3 to a field in a dataset also lose precision?  How is a macro variable different?

Comment: Looks the same to me: `data x;
  x = 1/3;
  call symput ('x',x);
  put 'DATASET: ' x best22.20;
run;

%put MACROVAR: &x;`

Comment: @RobertPenridge looks can deceiving you are looking at the formatted values.  It may be good enough for you but I don't want to worry about by doing something that's obviously unnecessary.46         data _null_;
47            set x;
48            xm = "&x";
49            put (x xm) (=hex16.);
50            run;

x=3FD5555555555555 xm=302E333333333333

Comment: So why not save the value formatted to the level of precision you need to the macro var?  Seems like common sense to me.  If I'm going to be performing calculations using macro vars, I'll keep as many decimals as are needed.  If I'm just going to use the macro var to display a rounded on a report, then I probably won't keep any decimals and may format it using dollar signs, comma separators etc..   Saying macro vars lose precision is just wrong, as it all depends on how the coder saves it.

Comment: My apologies - you simply say that you 'risk' loss of precision... which I guess is correct.

Comment: @RobertPenridge what kind of calculations involving macro variables?.  I don't use macro variables for calculations involving summary statistics or raw data.  Not really SAS MACRO forte.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress proc means from outputting your results in a new tab using the *noprint* option. Try this:

```
proc means data = your_data noprint;
    var variable_name;
    output out = your_data2 p95= / autoname;
run;
```